# moment.js format date as iso 8601 without dashes?

Tags: momentjs, isodate

How do I format a date as iso 8601 using moment.js but without the dashes and colons and setting the time to 0 e.g. if I have a date like this:

```
2016-10-08T09:00:00Z
```

How do I format as :

```
20161008T000000Z
```

Doing `moment(date).toISOString()` gives `2016-10-08T09:00:00.000Z` which is not what I want.

Comment: moment().format('YYYYMMDD') will give '20161008' for example. see more at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 4):

You can simply parse your input into a moment object and use [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to set time to `00:00:00`. Then you can use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to get a string in your custom format.

Here there is a working example using a string input, you can use the same code  also if your input is a javascript Date object.

```js
// Input date as string
var s = '2016-10-08T09:00:00Z';
// Reset time part
// var m = moment(s).startOf('day');  // no UTC
var m = moment.utc(s).startOf('day'); // UTC mode
// Format using custom format
console.log(m.format('YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss[Z]'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You want to be in utc mode for this.  Use `moment.utc`